# Microsoft Graph API SDK BatchRequest -Filter by userprincipalname returning empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to pull multiple users from Azure AD using microsoft graph api
with batchrequest with Dot Net Core Microsoft.Graph.Beta SDK using filter by userprincipalname.

```
 var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

 var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {

                new QueryOption("$filter",$"userprincipalname eq '{email}'"),
                new QueryOption("$count","true"),
                new QueryOption("$select","id,mail")
            };

var request = client.Users.Request(queryOptions)       
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "Eventual")
                .Top(1);

var requestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(request);
                emailWithRequestIds.Add(requestId, email);

var response = await 
               client.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

var responseList = await response.GetResponsesAsync();

  foreach (var key in responseList)
 {

  var email = emailWithRequestIds[key.Key];
  if (key.Value.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
       emailDictionary.Add(email, null);
    }
   else
    {
      key.Value.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      var responseContent = await key.Value.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      var parsedResponse = ValidateBatchResponse(responseContent, 
                           email);

      if (parsedResponse.Exists == true)
      {                             
       emailDictionary.Add(email,parsedResponse.Email);
      }
       else
       {
        emailDictionary.Add(email, null);
       }
     }
 }
```

The same request to users endpoint without batch is returning data, while inside batchrequest it is returning empty. Is there any limitation that batch endpoint to work with userPrincipalName while using sdk?

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with the code for calling the Batch endpoint?

Comment: Could you also show me the `ValidateBatchResponse(...)` method? If the HttpResponse content is not being casted correctly, you will get an empty Microsoft.Graph.User.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a limitation on the batch size. As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching):

> JSON batch requests are currently limited to 20 individual requests.

It doesn't have anything to do with your $filter. Because that works flawless with the users endpoint.

UPDATE:
After seeing the code, I think the issue lies in casting the HttpResponse content to a `Microsoft.Graph.User`. If the casting is not done correctly, it will show an empty `Microsoft.Graph.User`.

The following worked for me:

```
var responseList = await response.GetResponsesAsync();
foreach (var resp in responseList) 
{
    var userString = await resp.Value.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
    var userCollection = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GraphServiceUsersCollectionResponse>(userString); 
    var user = userCollection.Value.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This is not related to batch request size. I am only using 15 requests at a time

Comment: @SandeepK I've updated my answer. Does this solve it for you?

Comment: I will check and update. For now i implemented this using rest api instead of sdk